# VB.net WPF Trying to search a Bound ListView results come up Empty

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Here is the code for my textChanged event. I get the error "Too many Arguments 'Public Overload Sub New()'" on the line (results = new ListViewItem(x))
I have looked everywhere and cannot find a solution.

VB:

```
        Private Sub SearchBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles SearchBox.TextChanged

    Dim myDT As DataTable = VPS_Local_L801DataSet.PatientInfo
    Dim dr() As DataRow = myDT.Select("PI_Patient_FName LIKE '" & SearchBox.Text & "%' Or PI_Patient_LName Like '" & SearchBox.Text & "%'")

    Dim x(1) As String
    Dim y As Integer

    PatientList.ItemsSource = Nothing

    For y = 1 To dr.Count
        Dim results As ListViewItem
        x(0) = dr(y - 1)("PI_Patient_FName")
        x(1) = dr(y - 1)("PI_Patient_LName")
        results = New ListViewItem(x)
        PatientList.Items.Add(results)
    Next y

End Sub
```

xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="PatientList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="490" Margin="17,168,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230" SelectedValuePath="PI_SWUID" DisplayMemberPath="PI_UTIID" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Single"
              ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource CustomListViewItemStyle}" AlternationCount="2" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="White">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PI_Patient_FName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PI_Patient_LName}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>        

    </ListView>
```

The code works to where the ListView is populated when i go to search it clears the list but does not populate what is being searched.
Thanks

Comment: Check your query starts with and end is correct.. % sign

Comment: You say it's a bound list view, but then you clear the items source and manually populate items?  If you are binding to the default view of a data table, maybe try setting the `DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter` to your search criteria?

Comment: Thanks! the .RowFilter worked like a charm.